# In Doxygen, how do I overwrite a group title to remove the group warning saying "ignoring title %s that does not match old title %s"?

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-addtogroup

P.S. I am a doxygen newbie.

I have a few .c and .h files with a doxygen group format looking like this:

```
/** \addtogroup <label> <title>
 *  @{
 */

...

/** @}*/
```

When built, a warning returns that looks like this:

```
application/inc/xxx.h:14: warning: group <label>: ignoring title "<title>" that does not match old title "<old_title>"
```

What I want to do is to remove this warning. Can somebody help?

I read the documentation on the different doxygen mechanisms to group things together, mainly on "modules".

I saw that I can use \defgroup, \ingroup, and \addtogroup.

In the documentation, it stated

> If you don't want doxygen to enforce unique labels, then you can use \addtogroup instead of \defgroup. It can be used exactly like \defgroup, but when the group has been defined already, then it silently merges the existing documentation with the new one.

So, I tried searching the whole code base I was working on if there was any `\defgroup <label> <title>`. Safe to say, there was none matching the arguments I placed. Still, the warning kept showing.

Comment: which version of doxygen are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes in your case from the multiple use of the `\addtogroup` command with the same label but with the a different title (file name used aa.h).
like:

```
/** \addtogroup lab1 title1
 *  @{
 */

/** the first fie */
void fie1();

/** @}*/

/** \addtogroup lab1 title2
 *  @{
 */

/** the second fie */
void fie2();

/** @}*/
```

and a default settings file which leads to the warning (with the current doxygen 1.9.6 version):

```
aa.h:11: warning: group lab1: ignoring title "title2" that does not match old title "title1"
```

The title of the first `\addtogroup` encountered is in this case "promoted" to the title of the group as if it was from a `\defgroup` command.
So you should either

- see to it that all titles are the same for the same label
- use a title only ones
- add a `\defgroup` and omit the title with all the `\addtogroup` (or see to it that all the titles are identical)

Comment: I see.
When I do a ctrl+shift+f on "\addtogroup", I see that the first title with the label I had was the one in the warning line <old_title>. This made sense to me.
Thanks! Cheers!